# Rhythmbox and partially unknown listing

Tags: rhythmbox

I have a directory of .mp3 files from a CD, and Rhythmbox imported them and plays them without problem.

But the the first six tracks have "Unknown" for the information fields:

[image]

How can it get half the album details correct, and not the first half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's odd but perhaps it's a "bad" CD.
You can check if the songs actually contain metadata by opening them with [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60309/360892). If you can't see any metadata then I guess Rhythmbox isn't the one to blame here. Try [EasyTAG](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG), from what I hear it's pretty good.

Comment: Right.  "easytag" showed that the metadata was empty for the first 6 tracks.  How that happened, I've no idea, but now I can start all over again.  Thanks.